# Pass "restProps" through React-Select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-select

**THE PROBLEM:**
I have a simple Form Select Component. It has several props, and uses React Select V2, as the implementation layer. And I want to pass some extra props. Here is the code:

```
const SelectDropdownField = ({
  prop1,
  prop2.
  ...restProps
}: SelectProps): JSX.Element => (
  <Field
    name={name}
    render={({
      field,
      form: { setFieldValue, setFieldTouched, errors, touched }
    }: FieldProps<FormikValues>): ReactNode => (

      return (
        </div>
            <ReactSelect
                .. //someFieldsHere
                {...restProps} // this doesn't work
            />
            {JSON.Stringify({...restProps}, null, 2)} // this works
        </div>
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

I am trying to pass the `data-testid` attribute. But if I pass it inside the ReactSelect, it doesn't work. Outside of it, it works just fine. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after looking at the code, it seems impossible.

By checking [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/Select.js#L1819-L1856) the render function of react-select, we can see that the only way we could add custom props is via the `commonProps` object. But checking each child component, there's no where it reaches the DOM. Only `innerProps` reaches the DOM but the library user has no control over it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried experimenting with the innerProps as well, with no luck.. it seems that the component, to me at least whitelist only the usable props, and gives you no control over adding extra stuff.. Thank you for your time..